# Board surplus feature

Tags: feature-request

It would be extremely helpful if the CSE default FEN board would be accompanied with something like [this](http://bambam42.de/is/is167/s04.html): as you see, a little arrow indicates the side to move as well as the orientation of the board, both which can only be inferred from context now.